# how to remove <Technology> and </Technology> words from a file using shell script?

Tags: shell, sed

My text file contains `100` lines and the text file surely contains `Technology` and `/Technology` words .In which ,I want to remove `Technology` and `/Technology` words present in the file using shell scripting.

Comment: try `sed 's/[\/]\{0,1\}technology//g' youfile'`

Comment: answer edited with the option to show two command lines (backing up and not backing up the original file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak -e 's#/Technology##g' -e 's#Technology##g' my_text_file
```

This is delete the words and also make a backup of the original file just in case

```
sed -i -e 's#/Technology##g' -e 's#Technology##g' my_text_file
```

This will not make a backup but just modify the original file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

`sed -r 's/<[\/]*technology>//g' a`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @bartektartanus no, it does. If you feel that is a bad answer you can always downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

cat file

```
This Technology
More here
Mine /Technology must go
```

```
awk '{gsub(/\/*Technology/,"")}1' file
This
More here
Mine  must go
```

---

By adding an extra space in the regex, it will not leave an extra space in the output.

```
awk '{gsub(/\/*Technology /,"")}1' file
This Technology
More here
Mine must go
```

---

To write back to original file

```
awk '{gsub(/\/*Technology /,"")}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If you have `gnu awk 4.1+` you can do

```
awk -i '{gsub(/\/*Technology /,"")}1' file
```